# rails heroku query help PGError: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku

Im deploying a rails 3.2.8 with ruby 1.9.3 in heroku, locally the query shows all books as results or none, and in heroku it just shows the following error.

```
Started GET "/books/advanced_search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=elinor&author=&isbn=&commit=Search" for 157.253.204.87 at 2012-08-22 15:38:03 +0000

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "title"=>"elinor", "author"=>"", "isbn"=>"", "commit"=>"Search"}
Processing by BooksController#advanced_search as HTML
Rendered books/advanced_search.html.erb within layouts/application (24.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms

ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...tle LIKE '%elinor%' and author LIKE '%%' and isbn LIKE '%%')

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Im trying to find books in my mini catalog via title which is an string, author which is a text and isbn which is an integer, by any one of them or by all.

Heres my query:

```
@books = Book.paginate(
      page: params[:page], per_page: 10,
      :conditions => ['
                    title like ? ||
                    author like ?  ||
                    isbn like ?',
          { :title => "%#{params[:title]}%",
            :author => "%#{params[:author]}%",
            :isbn => params[:isbn].to_i
          }
      ]
  )
```

Heres the model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :isbn, :title, :description
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy

  validates :author,      presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :isbn,        presence: true
  validates :title,       presence: true


end
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the error happened because DBs do not do like queries with integers!